# a flap in "wedding" and "bidding"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, flapping

I'm wondering if a flap occurs in *wedding*, and *bidding* in American pronunciation? I can't hear it out here: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/wedding

Comment: That pronunciation is odd. It would normally have a flap in most American pronunciations (including General American).

Comment: Most Americans use flaps in these words, but not all Americans do. Think of a flap as one of several possible alternate American pronunciations, rather than the only genuine American pronunciation.

Comment: The pronouncer of "wedding" sounds American, but seems as if he was trying to be careful in his pronunciation, rather than natural.  The pronouncer of "bidding" at that same site sounds (to my American ear) British, or at least Canadian.

Comment: Well when you use the search function it automatically redirects you to the British version of the site so that explains some of it. I also searched a few other words that should have flaps and I noticed that some of the words including wedding and bladder have elongated vowels before what should be the flap. My guess is its cut and pasted audio because they don't have the actual recording or some sort of super good speech imitation program.

Comment: In the US we generally try to avoid flaps in weddings.

Comment: So just out of curiosity what the heck does everyone mean when they say "American Pronunciation?"  Does a guy from New York have American pronunciation?  What about someone from Baton Rouge?

Comment: @michael_timofeev - Albert Lea Minnesota.

Comment: @michael_timofeev https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American#Phonology

Comment: To those guys in London, we all sound alike...

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this is speed. As others have said, a lot, but definitely not all, Americans pronounce *wedding* and *bidding* with a lateral flap. But the thing to notice here is that the flap isn't an actual flap.

Here is the case with these words:
The *dd* (or just a *d* for our purposes) is surrounded by vowels which require the tongue to stay away from the palate. Since the tongue goes from a vowel (away from palate) to a consonant (touching palate) to another vowel (away from palate), a lateral flap is produced depending on how fast the sequence is spoken.

Comment: Is the flap usually lateral? I don't remember hearing that before.